# Grant our Azure App registration permission equivelant to Contribute without delete.... is this possible

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-appservice

I have an azure app registration named "Integration-Test", and i granted this app registration Write permission on selected site: -

```
Grant-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission -Permissions "Write" -Site $siteUrl -AppId $clientId -DisplayName "Integration-Test"
```

This Write permission, will mimic the Contribute permission inside SharePoint, where you can add,edit,delete items and documents, but you cannot modify, delete, add lists and libraries. but can i restrict this further so that app registration will have Write without delete, which mimic SharePoint contribute without delete permission level?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it is possible as you only have these options: `Read|Write|Manage|FullControl`. Also, "contribute without delete" is not a SharePoint default permission level.

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP i mean you can create a custom permission level in sharepoint to allow for Contribute without delete

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP then can i restrict the azure registration app to have permission on specific lists within the selected site? or this is not possible also?

Comment: As per my knowledge Azure AD app can have permissions at site level using `Sites.Selected` permissions but not at list level.